# F# group by more than one value and aggregate

Tags: c#, linq, f#, grouping

F#. I have a list `transactions` of the following type:

```
type Transaction(Debitor: string, Spend:float, Creditor:string)  = 
     member this.Debitor = Debitor
     member this.Spend = Spend
     member this.Creditor = Creditor
```

I know how to group by one value. Say for example I want to group per property `Debitor`, it's easy to use that property as the Key of the group:

```
let tsGroupDebitor =
    transactions        
    |> Seq.groupBy(fun ts -> ts.Debitor)
```

However, I cannot manage to group per two values, say `Debitor` and `Creditor`. Ideally, I would like to group considering `Debitor` AND `Creditor`, while appling an aggregator function "Sum" for the `Spend` property.

**In other words**, I'd like to achieve the F# equivalent of the following LINQ query:

```
 var transactions_GroupSameDebitorCreditor = 
     transactions
     .GroupBy(ts => new { ts.Debitor, ts.Creditor }) // group by multiple values
     .Select(gr => new 
            {
                Debitor = gr.Key.Debitor,
                Debit = gr.Sum(trans => trans.Spend), //sum the trans values per grouped relationships
                Creditor = gr.Key.Creditor
            });
```

Where a IEnumerable of anonymous type was returned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a tuple as the group key like this:

```
let tsGroupDebitor =
    transactions        
    |> Seq.groupBy(fun ts -> (ts.Debitor, ts.Creditor))
```

If you want to aggregate the transactions of each group to sum the Spend property, you can do it like this:

```
let tsGroupDebitor =
        transactions        
        |> Seq.groupBy(fun ts -> (ts.Debitor, ts.Creditor))
        |> Seq.map(fun ((debitor, creditor), values) -> ( debitor, creditor, values |> Seq.sumBy (fun t -> t.Spend)))
```

Notice how I use pattern matching with the pattern `((debitor, creditor), values)` to be able to access the two parts of the group key and the sequence of transactions for each group (`values`)

Comment: I see. So the last pipeline operator `|> Seq.sumBy (fun t -> t.Spend)` is applied only to `values` in order to sum only the `Spend` property, and the `sumBy` method is used to specify a function, which you couldn't with the `sum` method.
Very useful, thank you.

Comment: `sumBy` is a useful shortcut. You can do `values |> Seq.map (fun t -> t.Spend) |> Seq.sum` instead if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

```
let sumTransactions (transactions: Transaction list) =
    transactions
    |> Seq.groupBy(fun ts -> (ts.Creditor, ts.Debitor))
    |> Seq.map (fun ((cred, deb), ts) -> 
                    let s = ts |> Seq.sumBy (fun t -> t.Spend)
                    Transaction(deb, s , cred))
```